# Refilling xml file with data from sdf file

Tags: python, elementtree, ipywidgets, sdf

As I am very new to python, I have been struggling to finish the code.

I have an xml file with a small part I need to refill.

#### XML excerpt

This is the part that I need to refill.

````xml
<Definition>
    <Model> 
        <Xcaption>1</XCaption>
        <Ycaption>A</YCaption>
        <String>manynumbers</String>```
````

This is repeating 80 times in the xml structure

#### Problem and question

I am able to enter all the elements with `elementree`.

Yet, I need to take information from the *sdf* file, that has this data in different order.

I organized it with [`ipywidgets`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with drop-down value, yet I have trouble thinking forward to connect one with another.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I am able .." and "I organized" claims your effort so far, can you show us the code as [example], please. Please edit your question and paste the code you have so far.

Comment: Also: Can you show or explain the "sdf" file format and contents to us.